# How to validate a file upload in Symfony2 (ImageValidator)?

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I am currently developing an application which uses the newest version of Symfony2. I have some problems validating a form which includes a file upload field.

My form code looks like that (shortened):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;

    class EventEditForm extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add("name", "text", array("required" => true));
            //....
            $builder->add("image", "file", array("property_path" => false, "required" => false));
        }

        public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
        {
           $collectionConstraint = new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection(array(
                'image' => new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image()
                ));

            $options["validation_constraint"] = $collectionConstraint;
            return $options;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'editeventform';
        }
    }
```

As you can see here I want to ensure that the uploaded file is an image. I use the form like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new \Trancefans\AdminBundle\Form\EventEditForm(), $event);
```

But when running this code I get the following error:

> Expected argument of type array or Traversable and ArrayAccess, object
>   given

I really don't know where my fault is. I did it exactly as described in the documentation. Can somebody help me? :-)

BTW: The image is not represented by the event entitiy, but every other field of the form is. I use doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

`Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\CollectionValidator` requires that the data it's validating is an array or an object that implements ArrayAccess and Traversable.

Ensure that your class definition for the $event instance implements `ArrayAccess` and Traversable so when `CollectionValidator::validate()` is invoked it can access your values to validate them accordingly.